# 2004 Flash .SWF no longer working

Tags: flash

This flash file was made many years ago around 2004. It worked fine at the time. Lost the .fla when hard drive crashed but recovered the .swf file from the internet's WayBack Machine. It plays fine on the Wayback Machine's website. Recaptured the .fla using Sothink Extractor but I can't get it to work now.

Maybe it's outdated but can't afford to upgrade. I still have Flash MX 2004.

This is the way it was set up. I have a movie clip labeled Speaker. (Tried calling it a button but that didn't work either)

You click on the speaker and it goes to a labeled frame on the timeline and plays a lip synced message:

Here is the action script located in frame 1.

```
stop ();
speaker.onPress = function ()
{
gotoAndPlay(start_richard);
};
```

I have a frame on the timeline labeled start_richard. Yet if I click on the speaker nothing happens. Don't know why. Obviously, the coding is old but as mentioned is still play fine on Wayback Machine's website.

Comment: You probably mean a swf file and not fla? Is it possible that the sound was loaded from an external source? You might launch the swf in Chrome and watch connections to see if the swf is trying to load anything (F12 > Network)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It's the .swf that's not working. The sound was imported into the .fla and is located in the library. It is on the time line starting on the frame where start_richard begins. I'm baffled as this is such a small script.

Comment: That's strange. Try to embed the swf on your page with the exact the same HTML code as on the WayBack Machine's site?

Comment: Seeing how it's such a small script and a very small download I'm hoping it's not a big inconvenience to take a look at the actual .fla file to see what is going wrong.  It can be downloaded here. Promise no malicious virus or the like.    http://www.frontiernet.net/~wcowart/richard-online-demo.fla